# App crash due to inifinit scroll in mobile device

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, html

I have created cordova mobile app using angularjs. And there is a potential crash issue on infinite scroll.

Use case:
I want show a 500+ items in a list based on user scroll.(Remote pagination.)
Due the infinit scroll, app is crashed and my mobile become more hot.
I have used the chrome performance tool and Angular batarang. And I could see the dom usage is increased. And tried with couple of directive options(nginfinite scroll). But I didn't get any proper solution so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you have memory leaks somewhere ? If not you can use display:none; for elements what are outside of the viewport. Elements with display: none; will be removed from three view what could be perfomance boost.

Comment: The problem is likely that you're keeping all of the records in memory. When your app loads a new batch of results, you may want to drop some off of the beginning of your collection. So, if you fetch 50 results per AJAX call, maybe you limit the total number of items in the array to 60 or so.